# Laravel macros vs Inheritance

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about Macros in Laravel.

The idea behind these Macros is to add functionality to Laravel's built-in classes at runtime so that they can be used globally later.
In other words, the effect is the same as using inheritance.

Laravel macro

```
\Illuminate\Support\Str::macro('isLength', function (string $string, int $length) {
    return strlen($string) === $length;
});
```

Inheritance

```
class MyStr extends \Illuminate\Support\Str
{
    public static function isLength(string $string, int $length): bool
    {
        return strlen($string) === $length;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
\Illuminate\Support\Str::isLength('test', 4);
MyStr::isLength('test', 4);
```

I wonder what the difference is between this and regular inheritance (Not including that the methods being added at runtime), since the effect is exactly the same if I used inheritance.

So, what are the differences between these methods, and the pros/cons of each method, if any, because it looks like art for art's sake to me.

Comment: If you don't need to use any private method/property of build-in classes, I think inheritance is a better way than macros because you will not get any code completion on macros.

Comment: If you use inheritance you'd have to use your inherited class, rather than the Str class directly. Maybe you don't want to do that so a macro is an option to not do that

Answer (score 1):

Macros in Laravel comes from a `Macroable` trait which overrides `__call` and `__callStatic` functions. However with macro's, you can't override existing methods. If a method exists already, the magic function is not called so no macro function can be defined to act in it's place. Imho it's a pretty hacky way to provide extra functionality, also because it is added at runtime. But sometimes it's the fastest way to add something (since you can just call `SomeClass::macro('myFunction', ...)` in a service provider).

Extending on an existing class however gives you more possibilities + better code assist in your IDE and is the proper way to add functionality. But as you noted you have to refer to that new class explicitly yourself.

In conclusion, it depends on the situation: the bigger the change, the more likely you want to use inheritance :)

Comment: Would there be any performance issues using Macros? if I've 100s of macros defined in `AppServiceProvider` now on every request, framework would hold `static::$macros` in memory which I might not need to call most of the time (just for the sake of understanding)

Comment: I dont think its a huge performance concern since it only *creates* the macro functions. That being said, first-order functions in a custom class will be faster since those are not added at runtime. However if you need over 10 macro's for your application i think you need to take a look at the macros again and see if it can be done differently (good chance that similar functionality already exists in the framework).